# NSLog doesn't work in my blessed HelperTool

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nslog

To create custom packets and use libpcap, I've created a helper tool that run as root thanks to SMJobBless.
In my helper tool, NSLog doesn't send any logs to console.app.
I have to use syslog which send me logs in the console, but I've got problems logging objects issues.

Does anyone have an idea why NSLog doesn't work in such a blessed helper tool ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

3 years after, just found the answer: logs are sent by the HelperTool by root user.

Launching Console.app with sudo make the logs appear.

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea why `NSLog` doesn't work in this case, but since `syslog` works you can work around it like this:

```
#define MyLog(fmt, ...) \
    syslog(LOG_INFO, [[NSString stringWithFormat:fmt, ##__VA_ARGS__] UTF8String]);
```

or if you want to influence the log level:

```
#define MyLog2(level, fmt, ...) \
    syslog(level, [[NSString stringWithFormat:fmt, ##__VA_ARGS__] UTF8String]);
```

Put the macro in your `.pch` file so you can access it in all your source files. You can then use them like `NSLog`, even with just one argument:

```
MyLog(@"Test, test, 1 2 3");
MyLog(@"Content of object: %@", myObject);
```